# Linq to SQL use case and Lag equivalent

Tags: sql, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core

I have this SQL which I am trying to convert to LINQ , how can this be converted?

Is there an equivalent of Lag at all?

I see there is a case statement not sure how to use it

```
SELECT 
ah.AuthHist_ID,
ah.F_ID,
CASE WHEN ah.AuthPIFlg = 1 OR ah.AuthPINVFlg = 1 THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' end AS chkReqPI,
lag(CASE WHEN ah.AuthPIFlg = 1 OR ah.AuthPINVFlg = 1 THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' end, 1, null) OVER (ORDER BY ah.f_id, ah.AuthHist_ID) AS prevChkReqPI,
ah.Cr8Dt,
lag(ah.Cr8Dt, 1, null) OVER (ORDER BY ah.f_id, ah.AuthHist_ID) AS prevCr8Dt,    
cu.UserName AS Cr8UserName,
lag(cu.UserName, 1, null) OVER (ORDER BY ah.f_id, ah.AuthHist_ID) AS prevCr8UserName,   
fh.UpdtDt,
    FROM  AuthHist Ah
LEFT JOIN User cu
ON Ah.Cr8User_ID = cu.User_ID
WHERE Ah.F_ID = @fid


return (from a in DbContext.AuthHist
        join c DbContext.User on a.UpdtUserId equals c.UserId
        where a.FId == fId
        select new AuthHistEntity()
        {
            FId = a.FId,
            checkReqPI =  a.AuthPIflg = 1 || a.AuthPINVflg = 1 :
           
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have this SQL which I am trying to convert to LINQ , how can this be
> converted?

You can use linq to do this, but it will be a bit more complicated.

For the `case when` in linq, you can directly use **the ternary operator(?:)** instead.

As for the `Lag()` function, we need to replace this function with another sql writing as follow：
*(This is just to facilitate the understanding of the linq statement below, you do not need to change your sql statement)*

```
 select kh.AuthHist_ID,kh.F_ID,
    CASE WHEN  kh.AuthPIFlg = 1 OR kh.AuthPINVFlg = 1 THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' end AS chkReqPI,
    CASE WHEN (ch.AuthPIFlg is null or  ch.AuthPINVFlg is null) then Null when (ch.AuthPIFlg = 1 OR ch.AuthPINVFlg = 1) THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' end AS prevChkReqPI , 
    kh.Cr8Dt,
    ch.Cr8Dt  AS prevCr8Dt ,
    kh.UserName AS Cr8UserName,
    cu.UserName AS prevCr8UserName
    from
    ( select  -1+row_number() over (order by ah.f_id,ah.AuthHist_ID) as row1,  * from 
      (select * from AuthHist a left join User  u on  a.Cr8User_ID = u.User_ID) Ah) kh
      left join (select * from AuthHist a left join User u on  a.Cr8User_ID = u.User_ID) cu  ON kh.row1 = cu.AuthHist_ID 
      left join AuthHist ch on kh.row1 = ch.AuthHist_ID where kh.F_ID =@fid
```

Because the types of some fields are uncertain, I have create the AuthHistEntity class as follow, you can modify some details according to your needs.

```
 public class AuthHistEntity
    {
        public int AuthHist_ID { get; set; }
        public int F_ID { get; set; }
        public string chkReqPI { get; set; }
        public string prevChkReqPI { get; set; }
        public string Cr8Dt { get; set; }
        public string prevCr8Dt { get; set; } 
        public string Cr8UserName { get; set; }
        public string prevCr8UserName { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is the linq writing, you can try it:

```
var newUser = (from a in DbContext.AuthHist
                           join u in DbContext.User on a.Cr8User_ID equals u.User_ID
                           select new { a, u }).ToList();

var newAuthList = (from t in newUser
                  select new
                  {
                    row_1 = t.a.AuthHist_ID - 1,
                    data = t 
                  }).ToList();
int fid = 1;
var result = (from dt in
                (from ch in newAuthList 
                 join ah in DbContext.AuthHist on ch.row_1 equals ah.AuthHist_ID 
                 into ot from otnew in ot.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 select new { T1 = ch, T2 = otnew == null ? new AuthHist() : otnew 
                 }).ToList()
               join nu in newUser on dt.T1.row_1 equals nu.a.AuthHist_ID
               into yG from otnew in yG.DefaultIfEmpty()
               where dt.T1.data.a.F_ID == fid
               select new AuthHistEntity()
               {
                  AuthHist_ID = dt.T1.data.a.AuthHist_ID,
                  F_ID = dt.T1.data.a.F_ID,
                  chkReqPI = (dt.T1.data.a.AuthPIFlg == 1 || dt.T1.data.a.AuthPINVFlg == 1) ? "True" : "False",
                  prevChkReqPI = (dt.T2.AuthPIFlg == null || dt.T2.AuthPINVFlg == null) ? null : ((dt.T2.AuthPIFlg == 1 || dt.T2.AuthPINVFlg == 1) ? "True" : "Flase"),
                  Cr8Dt = dt.T1.data.a.Cr8Dt,
                  prevCr8Dt = dt.T2.Cr8Dt == null ? null : dt.T2.Cr8Dt,
                  Cr8UserName = dt.T1.data.u.UserName,
                  prevCr8UserName = otnew == null ? null : otnew.u.UserName
                 }).ToList();
```